# Where to download Festival TTS voice

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

Where can I download the voices available in Festival demo page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu Linux, detailed instructions on how to install other voices are here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677277.

The instructions could be transferable to other Linux versions.

Comment: Site is currently down. Try http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1BG26q50TUkJ:ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php%3Ft%3D677277+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 1):

An other perharps useful resource is [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751169) for MBROLA / CMU / HTS voices.

Note that not all the available voices work with Festival 2.4 and some are only compatible with version 2.1. This seems to be the case for the Nitech HTS voices, probably the best ones available. The CMU voices are a good compromise though.